# Gravity forms frontend repeating fields groups/section

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, repeat, form-fields, gravityforms

I need to create a form in gravity forms. Client need to full in the form and should be able to add sections with title, body and image. I can create the form but can't get frontend add fieldgroup or section to work. Anyone ideas how to make fields repeatable on frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a solution (Gravity Wiz team) called Nested Forms:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/

We wrote a guest post on the Gravity Forms website about it here:

https://www.gravityforms.com/repeatable-data-wordpress-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms does not allow creation of fields from the front-end.  All fields have to be created from the backend.

If you want to have some sort of repeatable fields try to use the list field with multiple columns and then style them with your own css.

If you want to change the input type of a particular column from text to dropdown you can use the `gform_column_input` filter which is described in further details [here](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_column_input/)

Answer (score 0):

I did export the form then duplicated them by copy paste in the xml file. Conditional logic changed numbers end now it works. This was the fastest option for me. Other solutions didn't have the right options.